# Determine if SelectBox containing no options exists using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

So this question is asked a lot on the net and I see the answer is to check if the .length is > 0.

So in my case a select box may or may not exist.  If it exists, it may have no options.

I have to code for the following:

If selectbox exists ...
  if there are no select box options ...
    disable a text area

I have therefore written the following:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    "use strict";

    alert('running globals');
    // Only process this block if the contactEmailAddress select box exists
    if ($('contactEmailAddress').length > 0) {
        alert('on the comm page');

        // If there are no contacts ...
        if ($('#contactEmailAddress option').size() === 0) {
            alert('disabling the message box');
            $('#message').attr("disabled", "disabled");
        }
    }
});
```

The problem is, because the select box has no options, it's decided the selectbox.length is 0.  So this block never fires.

I need another way.

Comment: `$('#contactEmailAddress option').size() < 1`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're missing the "ID selector" from the first `$`, instead searching for elements *named* `contactEmailAddress`, rather than elements with an *ID* of `contactEmailAddress`.

```
if ($('#contactEmailAddress').length > 0) {
```

Note you can just do `$('#contactEmailAddress option').size()` directly without worrying if the select exists or not; no exception or error will be thrown.

Comment: Lol typo!  Sometimes I just need another set of eyes.  Sadly I'm the only developer at this company, so I have no one else to ask to look at it.  Thank you again!

Comment: Also, good to know about the size option.  I'll skip right to it.

Answer (score 0):

You can determine an element exist with using pure javascript.

```
if( document.getElementById("contactEmailAdress") )
```

or

```
if( document.getElementsByClassName("option")[0] )
```

Comment: You probably want `getElementsByTagName` for the second example, and note that that will find *all* `option` elements on a page; not just those that are attached to the select box in question.